# Listen to computer audio with headphones plugged in

Tags: speakers

I have to do a training soon and sometimes I just want to take off my headphones and listen. I know I can unplug my headphones and listen through the speakers but I want to be able to answer if called upon for which I would need to have my headphones on. I was wishing the other day there was a way to switch from one state to the other-much like a speakerphone button on a phone. Does a thing exist on any headphones? I prefer Logitech obviously.

Comment: First, doesn't your PC have its own microphone? And if not, why not just plug in an external mic, *sans* headphone?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 as your operating system, you can achieve this by navigating to the Advanced Sound Options section of the Sound settings in Control Panel. Here you can specify the Input and Output device used by specific applications on your PC, such as a web browser or a video conference app.  This would allow you to keep your headset microphone set as the input, while using your actual speakers for the audio output.

Comment: This only work for Bluetooth headphones or unless it us on a PC. For laptop, audio is routed from speakers and inbuilt mic to the headphones with circuits and not by OS, at least in my laptop.

Comment: I am able to use this feature on my desktop PC as well as my laptop, both currently running Windows 10 though.

Comment: My laptop doesn’t. I’m looking for some other alternative so that I can keep my headset connected at all times. I also don’t require a dedicated mic for the time being.